# Use Azure AD with Active Directory PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to validate users in Azure AD using the following method,

```
  public bool ValidateCredentials(string domainName, string userName, string password)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
            {
                bool isValid = pCtx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
                return isValid;
            }
        }
```

I have provided the domain as "xyz.onmicrosoft.com" and the user and password under the respective azure AD. and 
received an exception "The server could not be contacted."

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD does not provide the same endpoints as Active Directory as the two are completely different products.

You need to use Open Id Connect or WS-Fed or SAML2 flows to authenticate a user.

Guidance for various scenarios here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios